# How to pass a String argument to ArrayList parameter

Tags: java, string, arraylist, parameter-passing, casting

I am trying to pass a String argument to a ArrayList parameter like so:

```
Class A {
 public void testA (ArrayList arrayInput) {
      // Implement function
      System.out.println("In testA function");
   }
  String a = "new";
  testA(a);
}
```

I do this because I want to use the same function to pass both String values and ArrayList values. Is there a work around?

Thanks,
Sony

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
// Option 1: print in String - preferred
public void testA(ArrayList<String> list) {
    for(String str : list) testA(str);
}

public void testA(String s) {
    System.out.println(s);
}



// Option2: print in List - not so preferred
public void testA(ArrayList<String> list) {
    for(String str : list) System.out.println(str);
}

public void testA(String s) {
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add(s);
    testA(list);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use the same function to pass both types, you must overload function:

```
    Class A {
     public void testA (ArrayList arrayInput) {
          // Implement function
          System.out.println("In testA function");
       }
     public void testA (String stringInput) {
          // Implement function
          System.out.println("In testA function. For String!");
       }
      String a = "new";
      testA(a);
    }
```

Or you can write a function with generic:

```
public void testA<T>(T input){...}
```

Comment: Pardon me if I'm wrong, but shouldn't this be overloading the function instead of overriding?

Comment: Umm..what if the implementations of both the overridden functions essentially produce the same output. If I pass an ArrayList with only a single element "hello" and print all the elements of the ArrayList, the output would be "hello". This would be equal to passing a Single String with value "hello". However, if the arraylist is longer, then I would print more values. Essentially, both the overridden functions have the same functionality - say printing in this case. This is a shorter example of what I am trying to do. Thanks !!!!

Comment: use generics than and check if T is String, than you write only one switch code for your "special" case.

Comment: @ultor that's a very poor decision... really... sorry buddy

Comment: @ultor Allow me to clarify: Your post is a great decision. Your comment about using generics, and then checking the type, THAT is the poor decision. I personally would do what is in the first part of your post.

Comment: @glowcoder: But overloading method would lead to duplicated code in my case. Please see my comment. What would you suggest?

Comment: you can write overloaded method and call method with ArrayList parameter. Your overloaded method must create new ArrayList with one element, and all will be done.

Comment: @sony I'll post an answer with your two options.

Comment: @sony It's worth noting that on SO it's generally considered a courtesy to upvote posts that put you in the right direction.

Comment: @glowcoder: Yes, I did after trying the code you suggested :) Thanks again !

Answer (score 1):

You could write overloaded methods as other answeres suggested.

Alternatively you could simply wrap the `String` object in a `List` and pass it to `testA` as shown below:

```
public static <A> void testA(List<A> list) {
  // some code that works over list
  System.out.println("In testA method");
}

String a = "new";
testA(Arrays.asList(a));
```